# C++ - Write an exe file

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

i create a simple program which can make exe file from created project, maybe it can called `How to make a compiler` but i wanna know how **c++** write exe file, simply ..

```
-----------------------------------------
```

Like Python, Python is a programming language that written in c. So its compiler created with `c` yes ?

Maybe you more expert than me, help me out !

How i can do it and what the function should i use ?
i am newbie in c++ and i develop an IDE for my own programming language !

Thanks before

Comment: A compiler or interpreter can be written in whatever language you like. You could write a Python interpreter in Python if you wanted to.

Comment: Holla, I always got downvoted for important questions !

Comment: Developing a compiler is about as difficult as programming tasks get. Definitely not something a newbie, beginner or even intermediate user could (or should) tackle.

Comment: @MichaelAntonius - Try reading them before posting them to make sure that they make some sense.

Comment: @Angew My first program (well, the second) was an IDE-compiler written in BASIC N88. I was 16 and the program was used to teach assembler at the Univ. But there was not SO at that moment...

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-Edition/dp/0321486811/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1363351118&sr=8-1&keywords=the+dragon+book+compiler

Comment: @Angew, wrong, compilers are stunningly simple. And starting exploring computer science from compilation is not such a bad idea, it might give you an insight into how things really work. But I'd definitely not recommend reading the Dragon book.

Comment: @SK-logic I wouldn't call even an LALR(1) parser alone stunningly simple. I've written a my_own_script_language-to-my_own_bytecode compiler, and it was far from simple. And it didn't have to deal with ambiguous grammars, processor instructions, standard libraries, system calls, ...

Comment: @Angew, you don't need LALR parser for a decent compiler. A trivial, no-brainer PEG is much easier. All of the intermediate code transformation chain can be fully declarative, you don't even need a full Turing-complete language for such thing, nothing but trivial rewrite rules all the way down to machine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use the word 'simply' when speaking of writing a compiler. It requires some serious knowledge about C++, assembly and system architecture. Writing a compiler for C++ is a massive project, just think of having to implement the standard library!

If you're really serious about writing a compiler for your own language, I'd start with writing an interpreter for a very, VERY simple language. When you've got that working, write a program to translate code from your language to C/C++ and use an existing compiler to generate your executable. Then you can start expanding on the language by repeating these steps for new concepts in your language. But really, I'd stay away from it.

Comment: I know interpreter is called as parser. But after parsing my language how to write it into exe ?

Comment: Why do you assumed that he want a C++ compiler??

Comment: hey @qPCR4vir JSQuareD is true, i want to write an exe file from few source code. So it called a compiler ???

Comment: @Michael Antonius, yes a compiler... but C++ or "your-lenguage- compiler" ?

Comment: Sure my-language's compiler

Comment: can you help me @qPCR4vir, sorry before ?

Comment: @Michael Antonio A compiler is a program that translates source code into machine code, an interpreter is a program which reads and executes human readable source code, without ever translating to machine code. Start by writing a very simple interpreter, then a simple translator to C, don't try to wrote an actual compiler unless you're an expert in assembly.

Comment: @qPCR4vir He mentioned both a C++ compiler and a compiler for his own language, so I just replied to both.

Comment: @JSQuareD right, wait ... wait assembly ?
So assembly can make an exe file for my source code ?

Comment: Assembly is the 'language of the cpu'. It's the actual machine code (0s and 1s) with names for specific combinations to keep it readable. But seriously, it's nothing a novice should ever concern himself with. If you REALLY want to write your own language, start with a simple interpreter. But even then, you should first familiarize yourself with the theory and languages involved.

Comment: I’m sorry to say No. I don’t know anymore. A native compiler is something very tricky. Even if you managed to create executable binary machine code the “.exe” file is much more than that. It deeply depends on the platform (the hardware, the O. System). The JSQuareD idea is very good – led other compiler generate the exe, and yours - generate code for that compiler.  (and make +1 for JSQuareD)

Comment: Thanks all, now i got the answer from you ! ...
God bless you ...

Comment: Next time maybe i can help you ..., hope Stackoverflow.com have a feature to adding friend hahaaha !